# Not able to connect to remote SQL Server using JavaFx application after generating a .exe application

Tags: java, sql-server, javafx, ant, javafx-8

I have written a small JavaFx application which will connect to a remote Ms Sql Server database and will fetch the records. Below is the java code for getting the connection connection to the Ms Sql Server.

```
public static Connection getConnection(){
    Connection connection = null;
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://<server-name>:<port>;"
            + "databaseName=TxnAnalyser;"
            + "IntegratedSecurity=true";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl );
        return connection;
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        showExceptionDialog(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I am running the code from Eclipse, I am able to connect to the server and is able to fetch records from the tables in the database. Then I created an **.exe** application using Ant (below is the `build.xml` file to create the **.exe**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="DBApp" default="do-deploy" basedir="."  xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
<target name="init-fx-tasks">
    <path id="fxant">
        <filelist>
            <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
            <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
            <file name="${basedir}"/>
        </filelist>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
        classpathref="fxant"/>
</target>
<target name="setup-staging-area">
    <delete dir="externalLibs" />
    <delete dir="project" />
    <delete dir="projectRefs" />

    <mkdir dir="externalLibs" />

    <copy todir="externalLibs">
        <fileset dir="C:\NotBackedUp\eclipse workspace\DBApp\lib">
            <filename name="sqljdbc.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="project" />
    <copy todir="project">
        <fileset dir="C:\NotBackedUp\eclipse workspace\DBApp">
            <include name="src/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="projectRefs" />
</target>
<target name='do-compile'>
    <delete dir="build" />
    <mkdir dir="build/src" />
    <mkdir dir="build/libs" />
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />

    <!-- Copy project-libs references -->
    <copy todir="build/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="sqljdbc.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Copy project references -->

    <!-- Copy project sources itself -->
    <copy todir="build/src">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <javac includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="Cp1252">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="build/libs">
                <include name="*"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>

    <!-- Copy over none Java-Files -->
    <copy todir="build/classes">
    <fileset dir="project/src">
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    </copy>


</target>
<target name="do-deploy" depends="setup-staging-area, do-compile, init-fx-tasks">
    <delete file="dist"/>
    <delete file="deploy" />

    <mkdir dir="dist" />
    <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />

    <copy todir="dist/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>


    <fx:resources id="appRes">
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="DBApp.jar"/>
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="resources/**"/>
    </fx:resources>

    <fx:application id="fxApplication"
        name="DBApp"
        mainClass="com.app.Main"
        version="0.0.0.1"
    />

    <mkdir dir="build/classes/META-INF" />



    <fx:jar destfile="dist/DBApp.jar">
        <fx:application refid="fxApplication"/>
        <fileset dir="build/classes">
        </fileset>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="Dev Team"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="DBApp"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="0.0.0.1"/>
            <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>
        </manifest>
    </fx:jar>


    <mkdir dir="deploy" />
    <!-- Need to use ${basedir} because somehow the ant task is calculating the directory differently -->
    <fx:deploy
        embedJNLP="false"
        extension="false"
        includeDT="false"
        offlineAllowed="true"
        outdir="${basedir}/deploy"
        outfile="DBApp" nativeBundles="all"
        updatemode="background" >

        <fx:platform basedir="${java.home}"/>
        <fx:info title="DBApp" vendor="Dev Team"/>

        <fx:application refId="fxApplication"/>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
    </fx:deploy>


</target>
```

But whenever I am trying to run the **.exe**, I get the following error and I am not able to connect to the database:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.8 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.<init>(SQLServerConnection.java:304)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1011)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at com.app.AppDBO.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.app.Main.start(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this error.

Comment: All you should need to resolve this is include `sqljdbc4.jar` in your Ant script.  Then this JAR should be available in your JRE 8 runtime.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you help me to add the `sqljdbc4.jar` and `sqljdbc.ddl` for the **.exe** application. As I totally new to Ant scripts and the above script was created using **_e(fx)clipse_ Eclipse** plugin.

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not too familiar with Eclipse.  You could always modify the script manually for an immediate fix.  Ideally, you can configure this from within Eclipse.